# @PreAuthorize in integration tests causing null beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm developing a security-related Spring Boot starter library to be consumed by other applications. The library comes with starter-like autoconfiguration that executes by default once the library is added as a dependency in the target application(s). What it does is it sets up a `filter` to run before an HTTP request is processed in order to perform some authorization checks.

What I want to do is write an integration test **within** the library that "simulates" the behaviour as when the library logic would run in a target application. That is, send an HTTP request to some endpoint, and test that the authorization checked worked (or didn't). My autoconfiguration looks like this:

**SecTestAutoconfiguration.kt**

```kotlin
@AutoConfiguration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  name = ["security.enabled"],
  havingValue = "true",
  matchIfMissing = true
)
open class SecTestAutoconfiguration {
   // multiple @Bean definitions that don't matter
}
```

Now in my tests, since there is no main class in the library, I am creating one under `src/test/kotlin/..`. like so:

**TestApplication.kt**

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
open class TestApplication
```

Then my IT test looks like this:

**AppIT.kt**

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "20000")
class SecurityIT {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var webTestClient: WebTestClient

  @Test
  fun test() {
    webTestClient.get()
      .uri("/test")
      .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "some-token")
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus()
      .isOk()
  }
}
```

and finally my test controller looks like this:

**TestController.kt**

```kotlin
@RestController
open class TestController(
) {
  @Autowired private lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext

  @GetMapping("/test")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_ROLE')") // This is problematic
  fun test() {
    println(applicationContext.id)
  }
}
```

The problem is that whatever I inject in my `TestController` seems to be `null`. This seems to be caused by `@PreAuthorize` since when I remove it, the `applicationContext` bean (or others defined in the auto-config) are getting properly initialized. Also tried with other spring-security annotations like `@Secured` or `@RolesAllowed` but getting the same outcome, `null` beans. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security uses Aspect Oriented Programming and proxies such methods with an AOP advice. This is why private methods are not working with such annotations as the calls by the proxy are not intercepted as they remain internal. Probably it is not verified here correctly and the unauthenticated processing is invoked.

I would try to move the @PreAuthorize into a service class with a test method annotated with @PreAuthorize. This should hopefully enable the correct injection and you can debug further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean create a `@Service TestService` class with a `test` method and move the `@PreAuthorize` there instead of the method in the `@RestController` class? If so, it doesn't seem to make any difference :/ Now, the beans are initialized at the controller class but still `null` when injected at the service.